# How to access an Exchange 2007 public folder via WebDav?

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, webdav

In Exchange 2003 I could connect via WebDav to a public folder via a URL similar to:

https://mail.myserver.com/Public/My%20Public%20Folder/

I'm trying to do the same thing in Exchange 2007 but cannot figure out the proper URL for a public folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this should not have been sop difficult.

Even though OWA doesn't use the same URLs, via WebDav I can use the exact same URL schema.

For example: https://mail.my2003server.com/Public/My%20Public%20Folder/ turns into https://mail.my2007server.com/Public/My%20Public%20Folder/

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem with an upgrade, though on an SBS server.  It took a while to work through as the WebDAV interface has now been "deprioritised", however after much debugging I found the following.

1. OWA authentication is now in an /owa not in /exchange and you can't change it.
2. Authentication had been changed to require NT authentication (and I think OWA authentication)

These were the problems not so much that the folder had had changed location.  In my case I altered my program to correct the security however altering some of the virtual web permissions, I think, also gave me access.

Comment: David, I'm able to authenticate, I just can't seem to "get" the object I want once I connect. The most relevant info I've found so far is at http://www.infinitec.de/post/2007/03/Constructing-OWA-2007-item-ids-from-WebDAV-items.aspx, however this isn't working for me.

Comment: Perhaps you could switch to using the webservice.  I didn't have any problem like infinitec.de.  I could still read the messages from the public folder using the href that was supplied.  Though it didn't work if the subject had been left empty, which is probably where their solution comes in.